# Returning multiple matches with levenshtein

Tags: php, levenshtein-distance

How can I return multiple similar matches with levenshtein in PHP? For example if I have this code:

```
$input = "Hello what is your name. My namer is Jack.";
$output = "nam";
echo levenshtein($input, $output);
```

It must not only output `name`, but `name, namer`.

How can I do that?

Comment: By looping through each word in your $input string, executing the levenshtein call against each word and outputting when the resulting distance is above your threshold for similarity

Comment: @MarkBaker How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$input = "Hello what is your name. My namer is Jack.";
$output = "nam";
$threshold = 3;
foreach(str_word_count($input,1) as $word) {
    if (levenshtein($word, $output) < $threshold) {
        echo $word, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```